# Mobile style sheet - only loads on refresh?

Tags: android, css, mobile

i have the following css calls:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="htlibery/desk_coupon_style.css" type="text/css"/>

<link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="htlibery/mobile_coupon_style.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

When viewing on iphone this serves the correct style sheet.

When on my samsung android (captivate) it serves the desktop version)

If i hit refresh the correct style sheet is then served.

any ideas...

If no ideas, what is the best method to auto refresh on page load?

Thanks

Comment: This is a guess but did you try changing the order they're linked? Something else you can do is append this querystring to the href attribute.

"?v=2" That will make sure it always takes the latest version.

Comment: @AlexMorales, I did reverse the order, and that did not help.. Ill try the version attribute and let you know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

So Far I have found this (From [paste bin](http://pastebin.com/70UTP96W)) to work best..

```
<!-- Mobile device detection by Bushido Designs: BushidoDesigns.net -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css"  />
 see note: <style type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 481px)"

 <!--
 @import url("screen.css");
 -->

 </style>
```

```
 <link href="mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="handheld, only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" />
```

I will update after further testing..

Comment: i tweaked the min-width to 800px so that when the phone is rotated it uses the mobile css... does that make sense or am i blindly hacking here?